# Testing interruptedException catch block in junit 5, breaks not migrated yet tests in junit4 scenario

Tags: java, maven, junit4, junit5

I'm trying to increase test coverage in our project, and I stumbled upon this issue:

```
...
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //Some logic
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); //Mostly to comply with sonar
    throw new CustomException("Message", e);
}
```

When I'm trying to test this catch block, tests are going smoothly for full junit5 scenario. Test here:

```
@Test //Junit 5 test
void someMethodShouldThrowInterruptedException() {
    //...
    when(someClass.doSomething()).thenThrow(InterruptedException.class);
    //...
}
```

But when JUnit5 testing scenario ends, and it jumps to JUnit4 tests, it randomly throws java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InterruptedException on random tests.

Besides migrating everything to JUnit5 or not testing this, do You have any other solutions how to make it work?

---

It looks like test runner is not waiting/killing all threads from JUnit5 scenario before it starts JUnit4 scenario. Then I think it reuses a thread that will be interrupted and breaks the scenario.

---

In maven, I'm using junit-vintage-engine 5.5.2, junit-jupiter-engine 5.5.2 and maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.2.

For context – Not all tests are migrated yet to JUnit5. It breaks randomly, I could pass all UT locally, on feature branch, but build after merging it to dev failed. Currently, I'm just not running this test. There was already a similar issue in JUnit5 ([Link](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1688)) and JUnit4 ([Link](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/1365)) but it was fixed for singular scenario runs, but in my case the problem occurs between scenarios.